# How do you prove this logical equivalence?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$\\ (\exists! x:P(x)) \leftrightarrow ((\forall x:P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))\leftrightarrow(\exists x:P(x) \land Q(x)))$

If there's only one $x$ for which $P(x)$, then saying "all $x$ for which $P(x)$, $Q(x)$" is the same as saying "there's an $x$ for which both $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$"

Edit: The first $\leftrightarrow$ was actually meant to be $\rightarrow$

Comment: This is an iff proof, so there are two things to do: (a) Assume $(\exists! x:P(x))$ and prove $(\cdots \leftrightarrow \cdots )$ (which itself is a double proof); and (b) Assume $(\cdots \leftrightarrow \cdots )$, and prove that $(\exists! x:P(x))$. ... Have you done any part of this?

Comment: The title seems to ask about proving a "logical equivalence", but the body of the Question seems to ask for confirmation of *meaning* (semantics).  If your interest lies in formal proof (e.g. via predicate calculus), then you should clarify this as the primary problem to be addressed.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman: Even if I assume $\exists! x: P(x)$ and $\forall x: P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$ I still don't know how to prove $\exists x: P(x) \land Q(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your last comment:

1) $∃!xP(x)$ --- premise

2) $∃x[P(x) \land \forall y (P(y) \to x=y)]$ --- from 1)

3) $∀x (P(x)→Q(x))$ --- assumed [a]

4) $P(x) \land \forall y (P(y) \to y=x)$ --- assumed [b] from 2) for $\exists$-elim

5) $P(x)→Q(x)$ --- from 4) by $\forall$-elim

6) $P(x)$ --- from 4) by $\land$-elim

7) $Q(x)$ --- from 5) and 6) by $\to$-elim

8) $P(x) \land Q(x)$ --- from 6) and 7) by $\land$-intro

9) $\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ --- from 8) by $\exists$-intro

> 10) $\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ --- from 2), 4) and 9) by $\exists$-elim, discharging [b]
>
> > $∀x (P(x)→Q(x)) \to \exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ --- from 4) and 10) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

*Conclusion:*

> $∃!xP(x) \vdash ∀x (P(x)→Q(x)) \to \exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$.

---

For the other part needed for the bi-conditional, we can prove it by contradiction:

1) and 2) as above

3) $\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ --- assumed [a]

4) $\lnot ∀x (P(x) → Q(x))$ --- assumed [b]

5) $\exists x (P(x) \land \lnot Q(x))$ --- from 4)

6) $P(a) \land \forall y (P(y) \to a=y)$ --- assumed [c] from 2) for $\exists$-elim

Now we need two new "nested" $\exists$-elims from 3) and 5), deriving respectively $P(b) \land Q(b)$ and $P(c) \land \lnot Q(c)$, with $a,b,c$ all distinct.

From $P(b)$ and $\forall y(P(y) \to a=y)$ from 2) we derive: $a=b$.

From $P(c)$ and $\forall y(P(y) \to a=y)$ from 2) we derive: $a=c$.

From $a=b$ and $Q(b)$ by $=$-elim we derive $Q(a)$.

From $a=c$ and $\lnot Q(c)$ by $=$-elim we derive $\lnot Q(a)$.

Thus, we have $Q(a)$ and $\lnot Q(a)$ and we derive: $\bot$ by $\to$-elim [$\lnot \phi$ is equivalent to $\phi \to \bot$]

In $\bot$ there are no occurrences of $a,b,c$; thus we can correctly conclude from 3), 5) and 6) by $\exists$-elim thrice with:

7) $\bot$

> 8) $∀x (P(x) → Q(x))$ --- from 4) and 7) by *Double Negation*, discharging [b]
>
> > $\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x)) \to ∀x (P(x) → Q(x))$ --- from 3) and 8) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

*Conclusion:*

> $∃!xP(x) \vdash \exists x (P(x) \land Q(x)) \to ∀x (P(x) → Q(x))$.

---

---

Thus, we have proved:

> > $∃!xP(x) \vdash ∀x (P(x) → Q(x)) \leftrightarrow \exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$.

One final application of $\to$-intro and we have proved that:

> if there's only one $x$ which is $P$, then to assert that "all $x$ which are $P$ are $Q$" is the same as "there's an $x$ which is both $P$ and $Q$".

Comment: In your first proof, when you do the Existential Instantiation (getting rid of the $\exists x$), you should really replace $x$ with something like $a$. (You did do this in the second proof.)

Answer (score 1):

> $$(\exists! x~:~P(x)) \iff (\forall x~:~P(x) \implies Q(x)) \iff (\exists x~:~P(x) \land Q(x))$$

The first thing to check is if it is actually true.  $\iff$ is associative and commutative, it just means that an even number of statements are false.

$P$ and $Q$ are unary predicates, so they are interchangable with unary sets (i.e., $P(x)$ is the same as $x \in P$).  So $\exists! x ~:~ P(x)$ is the same as $|P| = 1$, and $\forall x~:~P(x) \implies Q(x)$ is the same $P \subseteq Q$, and  $\exists x~:~P(x) \land Q(x)$ is the same as $P \cap Q \ne \emptyset$.

So the claim is equivalent to the claim that an odd number of the following statements are true:

- $|P| = 1$
- $P \subseteq Q$
- $P \cap Q \ne \emptyset$

So just trial and error, eventually trying out the first statement to be false and the last two true:

$$P = \{2, 3\}$$
$$Q = P$$

Is a counter example to the proposition.

Comment: The OP remarked that the first $\leftrightarrow$ was supposed to be a $\to$. This affects your answer.